# Preparing GIP record for PGRouting for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pgrouting

I have the GIP data set (https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/3fefc838-791d-4dde-975b-a4131a54e7c5) and would like to use it in QGIS with PGRouting.

Does anyone have an idea how I need to prepare the record?

Comment: So far, the dataset has source and target points and I'm able to use the time and length for costs. But I'm failing to visualize it in QGIS, I'm getting the error message, "invalid layer, no path found or failed to create a vector layer from query".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using QGIS from the beginning, you might better start with plain SQL queries. Because your data contains `source` and `target` attributes already, you probably have a valid network geometry already.

The [pgRouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/) is a good resource to start. It's using OSM data, so you may need to adjust the column names in your queries.